# How to select top value using two table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join

i Have two table

```
table1:itemTbale
table2:itemDetails


itemTable contain
id | itemName

itemDetails
id | itemID | price | details
```

table may contain data like this

```
  id | itemName
   1    Vechile
   2    Fruits


id | itemID | price | details
1      1      80$     bla bla
2      1      150$    bla bla bla
3      1      200$    bla bla
4      2       5$      ..
5      2       8$     ..bla
6      2       7$      bla..
```

Now i have to select top item details for each itemID

LIKE

```
 id | itemID | price | details  |itemName
 1     1       80$      bla bla   Vechile
 4     2        5$      ..        Fruits.
```

I am being little confuse with query.Help me
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: i am using sql server 2008

Comment: select min(price)..... group by itemID

Comment: i don't need to filter data using max(price)...I just need top 1 itemdetails For each itemID

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT D.id,
           D.itemID,
           D.price,
           D.details,
           T.itemName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY D.itemID ORDER BY D.id) AS row_num
    FROM   itemTable T
           JOIN itemDetails D
               ON T.id = D.itemId
)

SELECT id,
       itemID,
       price,
       details,
       itemName
FROM   MyCTE
WHERE  row_num = 1
```

Check out [this FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56f7b/2)